# Assigning array value not working?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

For a chess game I search for possible attackers on an enemy piece.
Board representation is done via a multi-dimensional array. `board[i][j]`, where i = row and j is column (so 8x8) and the value is the piece itself.

When searching for possible attackers I want to create a new array `aPossibleAttackers[i][j]`

```
var aPossibleAttackers = []; // create array
var ti,tj; // temp row/col
```

I do a search in all possible directions (0-7) and look for the first piece I meet. So direction and distance are known then. Then I calculate which field this is and want to copy the correspondending value from `board[i][j]` to `aPossibleAttackers[i][j]`. It's not working, though.

Code:

```
alert( veld(attackerRow,attackerCol) + " pos att op veld " + veld((attackerRow + (i * rowStep)), (attackerCol + (i * colStep))));

aPossibleAttackers[search_dir] = i; // searchdirection and distance, OK
ti = attackerRow + (i * rowStep); // OK
tj = attackerCol + (i * colStep); // OK
//aPossibleAttackers[ti][tj] = board[ti][tj]; // not possible????
alert("test2 ti= " + ti + " tj=" + tj + " ?? " + aPossibleAttackers);
```

What am I doing wrong?? `board[i][j]` does exist, or else I would not have found a piece.

Comment: What's wrong with `aPossibleAttackers[ti][tj] = board[ti][tj]`?

Comment: In errorconsole i get: Tijdstempel: 20-1-2013 17:45:54
Fout: TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
Bronbestand: http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx/javascript.js
Regel: 2021

Comment: That would suggest that either `aPossibleAttackers[ti]` or `board[ti]` is uninitialised.

Comment: `aPossibleAttackers = [] != aPossibleAttackers = [][]`

Comment: board array is the boardpresentation, which exists, else my code would be broken at start. I instantiated teh array aPossibleAttackers like this: var aPossibleAttackers = [], so it seems i just can't create a mulit-array by just saying: aPossibleAttackers[ti][tj] = board[ti][tj]; ??? Thanks Andreas, but how do i add board[i][j] to aPossibelAttackers??

Answer (score 0):

could be a string casting issue

try

```
alert( 
    veld(attackerRow,attackerCol)
    + " pos att op veld "
    + veld(((attackerRow*1) + (i * rowStep)), ((attackerCol*1) + (i * colStep))));

aPossibleAttackers[search_dir] = i; // searchdirection and distance, OK
ti = (attackerRow*1) + (i * rowStep); // OK
tj = (attackerCol*1) + (i * colStep); // OK
//aPossibleAttackers[ti][tj] = board[ti][tj]; // not possible????
alert("test2 ti= " + ti + " tj=" + tj + " ?? " + aPossibleAttackers);
```

just a guess